# How do Django queries 'cast' argument strings into the appropriate field-matching types?

Tags: django-models, casting, django-queryset, behavior

Let's take the Django tutorial. In the first part we can find this model:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

with which Django generates the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "polls_poll" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "question" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "pub_date" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

One can note that Django automatically added an `AutoField`, gloriously named `id`, which is akin to an `IntegerField` in that it handles integers.

On part 3, we build a custom view, reachable through the following url pattern:

```
(r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'polls.views.detail'),
```

The tutorial helpfully explains that a subsequent HTTP request will result in the following call:

```
detail(request=<HttpRequest object>, poll_id='23')
```

A few scrolls later, we can find this snippet:

```
def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
```

Notice how the URL tail component becomes the poll_id argument with a **string** value of `'23'`, happily churned by the `Manager` (and therefore `QuerySet`) `get` method to produce the result of an SQL query containing a `WHERE` clause with an **integer** value of `23` certainly looking like that one:

```
SELECT * FROM polls_poll WHERE id=23
```

Certainly Django performed the conversion from the fact that the `id` field is an `AutoField` one. The question is **how**, and **when**. Specifically, I want to know which internal methods are called, and in what order (kind of like [what the doc explains for form validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/)).

Note: I took a look at sources in `django.db.models` and found a few `*prep*` methods, but don't know neither when or where they are called, let alone if they're what I'm looking for.

PS: I know it's not casting *stricto sensu*, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's in [`django.db.models.query.get_where_clause`](http://djangoapi.quamquam.org/trunk/django.db.models.query-pysrc.html#get_where_clause)

Comment: ... which calls (among others, but this seems to be the one of interest for me) `connection.ops.field_cast_sql` with `django.db.models.fields.Field.db_type`.